# Error with generics - cannot find symbol class

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my first question. I'm beginner :-)

I have generic DAO (`CrudDao`):

```
public class CrudDAO<T> {

  @PersistenceContext
  protected EntityManager em;

  private Class<T> classePersistencia;

  public CrudDAO() {
    this.setClassePersistencia((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)
        getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
  }

  public T salvar(T entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
    return entity;
  }

  public T alterar(T entity) {
    return em.merge(entity);
  }

  public void excluir(T entity) {
    em.remove(entity);
  }

  public T buscarPorId(Long id) {
    return (T) em.find(getClassePersistencia(), id);
  }

  public List<T> buscarTodos(){
    return em.createQuery("from " + getClassePersistencia().getName()).getResultList();
  }

  /*Getter e Setter*/

  public Class<T> getClassePersistencia() {
    return classePersistencia;
  }

  public void setClassePersistencia(Class<T> classePersistencia) {
    this.classePersistencia = classePersistencia;
  }
}
```

and I have `DiasService`

```
public class DiasService extends CrudDAO<Dias> implements IdiasService {

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Dias buscaPorId(Long id) {
    return (Dias) super.buscarPorId(id);
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public Dias salvar(Dias dia) {
    return (Dias) super.salvar(dia);
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public Dias alterar(Dias dia) {
    return (Dias) super.alterar(dia);
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public void excluir(Dias dia) {
    super.excluir(dia);
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public List<Dias> buscaPorPeriodo(Date inicio, Date fim) {
    return null;
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public List<Dias> buscaTodos() {
    return super.buscarTodos();
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Dias buscaPorData(Date data) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

When I make compile I get error:

```
cannot find symbol class CrudDAO
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are these 2 classes from different packages? If they are, did you import CrudDAO?

If they are in the same package, kindly provide more details about the compiler error that you're getting.